# Use iPhone or iPod touch as an external hard drive

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak, ipod

I have an iPod touch 4g with 64GB storage space. Is there some way to store files of any file type on the device? I know that there are plenty of apps which let you share files via iTunes. Is there a way to make file storage independent from iTunes? Can I exchange data between a PC and a Mac that way?
I have read that you have to use Jailbreak to access the file system. Is there any other more "legitimate" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any apps or music on there, there's probably less than fifty GB available.  If you are that low on space, you might be better off with  a 64GB USB drive or SD card.

DropBox, OneDrive, iCloud, and their several competitors make it easy to keep files on it, but they also keep a copy of the same files on your other device.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after a quick search:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-share-transfer-files-from-pc-to-iphone-ipad/id1126257410?mt=8

YMMV

Comment: The better link would be : https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1126257410
Yes, we have built this app and you can transfer any file types to the app and store it without the need of iTunes. Rare file ( types ) get copied to Other Files folder. Hope this helps.